# Converting list to *args when calling function

Tags: python, list, arguments, function-call

In Python, how do I convert a list to `*args`?

I need to know because the function

```
scikits.timeseries.lib.reportlib.Report.__init__(*args)
```

wants several time_series objects passed as `*args`, whereas I have a list of timeseries objects.

Answer (score 283, accepted):

You can use the `*` operator before an iterable to expand it within the function call. For example:

```
timeseries_list = [timeseries1 timeseries2 ...]
r = scikits.timeseries.lib.reportlib.Report(*timeseries_list)
```

(notice the `*` before `timeseries_list`)

From the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls):

> If the syntax *expression appears in the function call, expression
>   must evaluate to an iterable. Elements from this iterable are treated
>   as if they were additional positional arguments; if there are
>   positional arguments x1, ..., xN, and expression evaluates to a
>   sequence y1, ..., yM, this is equivalent to a call with M+N positional
>   arguments x1, ..., xN, y1, ..., yM.

This is also covered in the python tutorial, in a section titled [Unpacking argument lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), where it also shows how to do a similar thing with dictionaries for keyword arguments with the `**` operator.

Comment: Forgot this: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#calls

Comment: lifesaver! i spent longer than I am going to admit trying to make a similar thing work! thanks ;-)

Answer (score 27):

yes, using *arg passing args to a function will make python unpack the values in arg and pass it to the function.

so:

```
>>> def printer(*args):
 print args


>>> printer(2,3,4)
(2, 3, 4)
>>> printer(*range(2, 5))
(2, 3, 4)
>>> printer(range(2, 5))
([2, 3, 4],)
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

`*args` just means that the function takes a number of arguments, generally of the same type.

Check out [this section](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) in the Python tutorial for more info.

Comment: I think the OP already knows this. The function takes multiple args but they have a single list they want to pass in as multiple args.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: The docs I linked to explain how to do that.

Comment: while that's true, the way you worded your answer it sounds like the link points to somewhere else. I think your answer will be more useful if you reword it to address unpacking rather than what *args means.

Comment: Could you provide a qualitative citation for the "generally of the same type" part?