# Removing only certain associations of many-to-many in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a many to many relationship between tags and restaurants. What I want to do is remove the association between the two given a list of tags.

For example, say `restaurant.tags.all()` produces these tags: ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5']

Is there a way I can do restaurants.tags.remove??(['t2','t4']) so that the results of `restaurant.tags.all()` is now: ['t1', 't3', 't5'] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use remove. Check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.remove

In your case, you would need a reference to the tags and not their string representations.

```
tags_to_be_removed = Tags.objects.filter(pk__gte=5) # use your filter
restaurant.tags.remove(*tags_to_be_removed)
```

We want to convert the list into args for `remove` [Converting list to *args in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941517/converting-list-to-args-in-python)

Comment: Ok, but what if I wanted to remove a queryset or list? Like what gets returned when you do Tags.objects.filter(...). This is my actual use case. Is there a way to do restaurant.tags.remove(list/queryset)?

Comment: Well you can always do `for t in queryset: restaurant.tags.remove(t)`, and then save restaurant. I'll have to see what happens if you pass in a queryset to remove.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about doing that, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way of doing this. Thank you for the input!

Comment: @MichaelSmith Well turns out you can use that list of filtered tags as args for remove directly and it works! Something I got to learn as well. Thanks!