# How to await a list of tasks in python?

Tags: python, c#, async-await, python-asyncio

In .Net C#, there is a function `Task.WhenAll` that can take a list of tasks to await them. What should I use in python? I am trying to do the same with this:

```
tasks = ...  # list of coroutines
    
for task in tasks:
    await task
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After adding tasks to a list, you should use [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) that gives coroutines as an argument list and executes them asynchronously. Also, you could use [`asyncio.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) that takes a coroutine and calls concurrent tasks in the event loop.

```py
import asyncio


async def coro(i):
    await asyncio.sleep(i//2)


async def main():
    tasks = []
    for i in range(5):
        tasks.append(coro(i))
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.close()
```

Comment: Looks good, I will try it. Can you also explaine what does '*' stands for?

Comment: In short, `asyncio.gather(*tasks)` is the same as `asyncio.gather(coro(0), coro(1), coro(2), coro(3), coro(4))`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941517/converting-list-to-args-when-calling-function).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) if you're on Python 3.7 or above. From the docs:

> Run awaitable objects in the aws sequence concurrently.
> If any awaitable in aws is a coroutine, it is automatically scheduled as a Task.
> If all awaitables are completed successfully, the result is an aggregate list of returned values. The order of result values corresponds to the order of awaitables in aws.